# At least how many numbers of the set $\{1,2,...30\}$ be deleted so that the difference of no pairs of the members of that set equals $10$?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> At least how many numbers of the set $\{1,2,...30\}$  be deleted so that the difference of no pairs of the members of that set  equals $10$?

I found 10 pairs having a difference of 10:
$1,11 - 2,12 - 3,13 - 4,14 ....  10,20 $. I think if we select one number from each pair,the condition would be met,but is 10 the minimal answer?

Comment: What about $(11,21) , (12,22) ... (20,30)$?

Comment: "the condition would be met,but is 10 the minimal answer?"  Welp.  I think the obvious next step is to prove via pigeon hole that any 21 numbers from 1.... 30 must have a pair whose difference is 10.  Work on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,29,30\}$ be such that $10\not\in(A-A)$.
Let $S_1=\{1,11,21\},S_2=\{2,12,22\},\ldots,S_{10}=\{10,20,30\}$.

If $|A|\geq 21$, by the pigeonhole principle there is some $k$ such that $S_k\subseteq A$, leading to a contradiction (if $S_k\subseteq A$, then $10\in(A-A)$). It follows that the maximum size of $A$ is $20$ as conjectured. In such a case $A=[1,10]\cup[21,30]$.

Comment: So you mean $10$ is the minimum number of members to be deleted?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks :) ,  +1.